# Why the ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent doesn't rename the file correctly if it exists?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hy,

I use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent in my application, to let the users to choice the path of downloaded file. It works fine, when the file name is unique.

According to documentation, if the file name is exists, the system doesn't overwrite the original file, instead of that, the system appends the number to the end of the file.

I tried the original android example, and first, when there is no other file with the same name, the file is created perfectly, and I can open, but when I would like to save the file in the same name, athought the system appends the number, not before extension , but after the extension something like this: `fileName.jpg(1)`, and after that I can not open, until then I delete this appended string.

I tried only my Samssung Galaxy S20 with Android 10, it is a specific issue, or did I something wrong?

Maybe it will be a good solution, if I could check the file name, before the save, but the document tree creates the file.

I tried this code, from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file):

```kotlin
const val CREATE_FILE = 1

private fun createFile() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/pdf"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "invoice.pdf")

    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Why the Document tree rename function doesn't work?` I see no rename function.

Comment: Sorry, I updated, maybe it is more understandable now

Comment: There still is no rename function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no extension (given by the MIME type) after the file name, android will automatically add it. That is fine.

Now it will find out if a file with this name exists and if so, it will add  `(1)` **after the part written by user**.

These examples show how the file name evolved:

```
"invoice.pdf" -> "invoice.pdf" -> "invoice.pdf (1)"
"invoice" -> "invoice.pdf" -> "invoice (1).pdf"
```

So just don't put the extension in EXTRA_TITLE:

```kotlin
const val CREATE_FILE = 1

private fun createFile() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/pdf"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "invoice")

    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. I remove the pdf extension from EXTRA_TITLE and it works :D

Comment: In my case, this code is prompting me to enter the file name to save.  Any idea ? what could be the issue ?                                                                                                                              val fileIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "application/pdf"
            val fileName =  System.currentTimeMillis().toString()
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName)
        }
        pdfFileIntentLauncher.launch(fileIntent)

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick a directory.

After that you can decide if the user determines the name of a new file or that your app does it.

Anyhow you can now check if a file name is already in use by for instance listing the contents of the directory. Or on another way.

If the file already exists then obtain the uri for that file and use it to overwrite the content.

Comment: Thanks, I see this, but it doesn't help me, I would like to save files to the download directory, with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE user can't choose the download folder. So I still have to use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. And also, I don't want to overwrite the file, rather than, I want to create new file, and append a number at the end of the file

Comment: Indeed on Android 11 the Download directory cannot be choosed. Are you downloading anything? Then if not you should not use that directory to begin with.

Comment: But on an Android 11 device you do not need saf to write to the Download directory. Just use classic file means as you did before. No permissions needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my final solition is that, I let the user to choose the directory, and after that I create the file with the default name, but I it is exsists the DocumentFile.createFile() will append correctly a number at the end of the file

Comment: Is there a way to save the directory uri which was choosed the user, maybe in to the database or shared pref, and next time, the application desn't ask user where to store the file, but use the previously choosed directory?

Comment: Yes. Shure. In onActivityResult save data.getData().toString() to shared preferences. If you wanna use it later you also have to take persistable uri permissions in onActivityResult. Indeed: the user has to choose only once.